# Node.js vs. Rust, but Node.js is faster

Tags: javascript, node.js, rust, memoization

I have a function named

> grid

which is from the dynamic programming problem "grid Traveler". I wrote the same function twice in JavaScript and Rust and benchmarked 10 million calculations whilst memoizing both functions.

JavaScript:

```
const grid = (m, n, memo) => {
    const key = m + ',' + n;
    if (key in memo) return memo[key]
    const max = Math.max(m, n)
    const min = Math.min(m, n)
    const d = Array.from({ length: max }, () => 1)
    for (let i = 1; i < min; i++) {
        for (let j = i; j < max; j++) {
            const index = j
            if (i === j) {
                d[index] *= 2
            } else {
                d[index] = d[index] + d[index - 1]
            }
        }
    }
    memo[key] = d[max - 1]
    return d[max - 1]
}


let start = new Date().getTime()
const memo = {}
for (let i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
    // grid(18, 18)
    grid(18, 18, memo)
}
console.log(new Date().getTime() - start)
```

Rust:

```
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::time::SystemTime;

fn grid(m: &usize, n: &usize, memo: &mut HashMap<String, u64>) -> u64 {
    let key = m.to_string() + "," + &n.to_string();
    match memo.entry(key) {
        Entry::Occupied(x) => *x.get(),
        Entry::Vacant(v) => {
            let max: &usize;
            let min: &usize;
            if m > n {
                max = &m;
                min = &n;
            } else {
                max = &n;
                min = &m;
            }
            let mut d = Vec::<u64>::with_capacity(*max);
            for _ in 0..*max {
                d.push(1);
            }
            for i in 1..*min {
                for j in i..*max {
                    if i == j {
                        d[j] *= 2;
                    } else {
                        d[j] = d[j] + d[j - 1];
                    }
                }
            }
            v.insert(d[*max - 1]);
            return d[*max - 1];
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let start = SystemTime::now();
    let mut memo = HashMap::<String, u64>::new();
    let m = 18;
    let n = 18;
    for _ in 0..10_000_000 {
        grid(&m, &n, &mut memo);
        // grid(&m, &n);
    }

    println!("{}", start.elapsed().unwrap().as_millis());
}
```

Benchmark results with commands:

> node index.js = 9

> cargo run --release = 1614

I thought maybe using a hashmap is not such a great idea, so I tried the #[memoize] macro from [this crate](https://crates.io/crates/memoize).

Results were yet disappointing:

> node index.js = 9

> cargo run --release = 254

Why is this happening and what’s the optimal solution to generally memoize this function in Rust?

Also benchmark results without memoization:

> node index.js = 15424

> cargo run --release = 2400

(Changes from Chayim Friedman) + (Switching to 100 million calls):

Rust:

```
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;
use std::time::Instant;
use rustc_hash::FxHashMap;

fn grid(m: usize, n: usize, memo: &mut FxHashMap<(usize, usize), u64>) -> u64 {
    let key: (usize, usize) = (m, n);
    match memo.entry(key) {
        Entry::Occupied(x) => *x.get(),
        Entry::Vacant(v) => {
            let max: &usize;
            let min: &usize;
            if m > n {
                max = &m;
                min = &n;
            } else {
                max = &n;
                min = &m;
            }
            let mut d = Vec::<u64>::with_capacity(*max);
            for _ in 0..*max {
                d.push(1);
            }
            for i in 1..*min {
                for j in i..*max {
                    if i == j {
                        d[j] *= 2;
                    } else {
                        d[j] = d[j] + d[j - 1];
                    }
                }
            }
            v.insert(d[*max - 1]);
            return d[*max - 1];
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let start = Instant::now();
    let mut memo = FxHashMap::<(usize, usize), u64>::default();
    for _ in 0..100_000_000 {
        grid(18, 18, &mut memo);
    }
    println!("{}", start.elapsed().as_millis());
}
```

It is still around ***four times slower*** than Node.js.

> node index.js = 54

> cargo run --release = 236

---

The problem is solved and details are in comments.

Comment: First, take `usize` and not `&usize`. Also, don't use `to_string()` for the key, but rather store a tuple `(m, n)`. Lastly, the default hasher in Rust is very slow: replace it with [`FxHashMap`](https://docs.rs/rustc-hash/latest/rustc_hash/type.FxHashMap.html).

Comment: And don't use `SystemTime` for benchmarking, use `Instant`.

Comment: I guess the `FxHashMap` change alone will give you the performance you want, because this is the main change from JS.

Comment: Side note: The memoize-crate supports using custom hashers: `#[memoize(CustomHasher: rustc_hash::FxHashMap, HasherInit: rustc_hash::FxHashMap::default())]`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman adding the changes you mentioned and doing 100 million function calls I still got 236 milliseconds on rust and 54 milliseconds on nodejs which is still disappointing

Comment: Instead of `Vec::with_capacity()` then lots of `push()`es, use `vec![1; *max]`. Also, use `usize` and not `&usize` for `min` and `max` (`&usize` is pretty much useless).

Comment: I think I got it: you're using constant `18` for `m` and `n`. This means `memo` will only have one property. JS engine optimize such cases to not use hashmap but rather structure with fixed offsets. So while the Rust code is performing full hashmap lookup each time (which is fast but...) the JS code only does some quick checks then constant offset access, which is basically free. Now I guess this is not your real use-case, so benchmark with varying numbers.

Comment: In other words, the equivalent code in Rust is not yours but code that assigns (and reads from) a struct with an `Option` field, which will be a lot faster than your JS code, probably so fast that you cannot even measure it.

Comment: If you don't want to (or can't) use varying numbers, change the JS code to use `Map` instead of an object, this should make it equivalent to the Rust code.

Comment: After changing the JS code to use `Map`, it executes in 20 seconds on my computer, so _somewhat_ slower than the Rust code.

Comment: one other side note I would like to mention is creating a vector with max capacity and pushing items one by one is faster that vec![1; max] 
around 100 milliseconds faster on 100 million runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only ever invoke `grid()` with one key (`18, 18`), the [inline cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_caching) optimization kicks in, and V8 transforms the map lookup in `memo` (which dominates the time) into a field offset access in object, which is basically free, while the Rust code still has to perform full map lookup.

If you use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in JS instead of an object, the JS code executes in about 20 seconds on my computer, so Rust is a lot faster. Alternatively, use variable `m` and `n`, so that the runtime is dominated by the calculation and not by the lookup.